# Cómo descargar archivos desde una carpeta compartida con PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Amigos, logré ingresar a mi carpeta compartida de la siguiente manera:
Fui al server en donde tenía la carpeta y saqué la ruta real:

```
function pre_r($array){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
}

$local_dir = '\\\\Servidor\ns\DESCARGAS\DOCUMENTOS';

$files = scandir($local_dir);

pre_r($files);
```

Ahora cuando intento descargar hago esto:

```
    <tr>
    
    <td><?php echo $fecha;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ruc;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $razonSocial;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $documento;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ruta;?></td>
    <?php
    $rutaNueva = substr_replace($ruta,'', 0,23);<- Dejo solo el nombre del archivo y elimino la ruta.
    $rutaFin = substr_replace($rutaNueva,'',-4);
    
    ?>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="descarga('<?php echo strtolower($rutaFin);?>');">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> <-- Desde aqui envio la ruta a descargar
</tr>
```

Este es el codigo por donde envío la ruta:

```
function descarga(ruta){
console.log("Descargando : " +ruta);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./action/descarga.php",
    data: "ruta="+ ruta,
    beforeSend: function(objeto){

    },
    success: function(){

    },
})
```

}

Y aqui lo trato de descargar:

```
<?php
$ruta = $_GET['ruta'];
$archivo = basename($ruta);
$url = "\\\\Servidor\ns\DESCARGAS\DOCUMENTOS".$ruta;

header("Content-Description: Descargar imagen"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$ruta");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($url)); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 

readfile($url); 
?>
```

Y aún así no me descarga, acotar dos cosas, quiero descargar archivos xml, y la ruta que le mando, se lo estoy mandando sin extensión, y la ruta se la concateno luego, ¿es necesario poner '' al final del string en la variable $url antes de concatenar $ruta?

Agradecería mucho su ayuda y consejos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré solucionar mi problema, primero saqué la ruta real de la carpeta compartida, desde el mismo servidor, desde aquí envío la ruta:

```
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $sede;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fecha;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ruc;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $razonSocial;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $documento;?></td>        
    <?php
    $rutaNueva = substr_replace($ruta,'', 0,23);
    ?>
    <td><a href="./action/descarga.php?ruta=<?php echo strtolower($rutaNueva);?> "><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

Y aquí lo recibo:

```
if(isset($_GET['ruta'])){

$ruta = $_GET['ruta'];
$url = '\\\\Servidor\ns\DESCARGAS\DOCUMENTOS\\'; <-- Ruta original de la carpeta compartida, desde el servidor donde se creo.
$file = $url . $ruta;
if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file); 
    exit;
}
```

Y de esa manera me descarga.